# Are there any recent studies of the incidence of atrioesophageal fistula as a complication of cryoballon ablation for afib?

Tags: surgery, cardiology, cryotherapy

I have found some reports online after searching and although the paper is 2018 the studies referenced may actually be considerably older and the technique may have been improved  since then.

*Surely I don't want anyone to use their valuable time to seach.* I have done it. So I am hesitant to even post this. I am wanting to know if someone may be familiar with the proceedure and just happens to know a recent paper or just first hand knowledge of the proceedure. Someone may have recently run across some information that may be useful for me. Not so sure my tags are appropriate.

These are the links to my research:

https://www.hmpgloballearningnetwork.com/site/eplab/articles/esophagus-and-atrial-fibrillation-ablation-anatomical-considerations-and-practices

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5889802/

Comment: What paper, please? That would prevent us from citing what you already know/refrenced.

Comment: If you have a paper in hand, and are wondering about work done more recently, a good first step is to find the original paper on Google Scholar and click the "Cited By" link to get you to: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=8080609724361311694&as_sdt=5,50&sciodt=0,50&hl=en - since it's likely that future papers about something very similar will cite the previous paper. Of course not entirely foolproof (especially if it's not the main point of the paper, or in a very active literature, or if authors simply missed the paper), but a good start.

Comment: You can also use the "search within citing articles" to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: I've edited your question to move the links from comments to the question. In the future, please put links to your research in the question itself, not in comments. Comments are subject to deletion at any time, and not everyone reads comments.

Comment: I don't think you meant _tracheoesophageal_ fistula. Tracheoesophageal fistula is usually congenital while _atrioesophageal_ fistula is a rare complication of atrial ablations (both cryo and RF).

Comment: @Carey Gregory. You are correct thank you!   That would make things very confusing. The question needed to be edited for that mistake as well.

Comment: I will use scholar google to see if I can find more recent articles.